# Apache Sqoop Incremental import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, incremental-build

I understand that Sqoop offers couple of methods to handle incremental imports

> Append mode
>
> lastmodified mode

**Questions on Append mode:**

1. Is the append mode supported only for the check column as integer data type? What if i want to use a date or a timestamp column but still i want to only append to the data already in HDFS?
2. Does this mode mean that the new data is appended to the existing HDFS file or it picks only the new data from the source DB or both?
3. Lets say that the check-column is an id column in the source table. There already exists a row in the table where the id column is 100. When the sqoop import is run in the append mode where the last-value is 50. Now it imports all rows where the id > 50. When run again with last-value as 150, but this time the row with the id value as 100 was updated to 200. Would this row also be pulled?

Example: Lets say there is a table called customers with one of the records as follows. The first column is the id.

100 abc xyz 5000

When Sqoop job is run in the append mode and last-value as 50 for the id column, then it would pull the above record.

Now the same record is changed and id also gets changed (hypothetical example though) as follows

200 abc xyz 6000

If you run the sqoop command again, would this pull the above record as well was the question.

**Questions on lastmodified mode:**

1. Looks like running sqoop with this mode would merge the existing data with the new data using 2 MR jobs internally. What is the column that sqoop use to compare the old and the new for the merge process?
2. Can user specify the column for the merge process?
3. Can more than one column be provided that have to be used for the merge process?
4. Should the target-dir exist for the merge process to happen, so that sqoop treats the existing target dir as the old dataset? Otherwise, how would Sqoop what is the old data set to be merged?

Answer (score 0):

**Answers for append mode:**

1. Yes, it needs to be integer
2. Both
3. Question is not clear.

**Answers for lastmodified mode:**

1. Incremental load does not merge data with lastmodified, it is primarily to pull updated and inserted data using timestamp.
2. Merge process is completely different. Once you have both old data and new data, you can merge new data onto old data to a different directory. You can see detailed explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXBbFz9Ty8I&list=PLf0swTFhTI8rJvGpOp-LujOcpk-Rlz-yE&index=14).
3. Merge process works with only one field
4. target-dir should not exist. The video covers complete merge process

Comment: For Q3 in the append mode, i have updated the original question. I think the answer is yet to that as well.

Comment: I see this statement from the apache sqoop cookbook, "Internally, the lastmodified incremental import consists of two standalone 
MapReduce jobs. The first job will import the delta of changed data similarly to normal import. This import job will save data in a temporary directory on HDFS. The second job will take both the old and new data and will merge them together into the final output, preserving only the last updated value for each row."

Comment: Figured out that for the incremental lastmodified mode, provided merge-key with the same target-dir as the base would result in 2 MR jobs and the base directory is the merged output. The history is lost though.

Comment: Which version of sqoop is it? I have checked on latest version of sqoop 1 and I did not see merge-key option as part of sqoop import.

Comment: The one that is bundled with HDP 2.3

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username hive --password hive --table Persons --merge-key PersonID --incremental lastmodified --check-column lastupdated --last-value "2015-12-22" --target-dir /practice/sqoop/example-2/incr-lastupdate/out/base......here the base folder already exists with some data...In fact, you run without the merge-key with the existing folder, sqoop suggests you to use either the merge-key or the append.

Comment: Thank you, it is working on hdp23 which have sqoop 1.4.6. It is not working on top of sqoop 1.4.5 version.

Comment: I doubt...The sqoop cookbook which i have is the 2013 edition....It should work in earlier versions as well according to the book.

Comment: Yes, it is working on Cloudera as well, probably there might be typo earlier.

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju: I keep getting illegal partition error for incremental import with merge key. Could you please explain why?